# How can I enable italic correction for LuaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, opentype, italic-correction

LuaTeX ignores mathematical italic correction by default, [as noted](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2011-October/030295.html) by Khaled Hosny.

This leads to some awful errors when using some alphabet which is very slanted, like XITS' mathematical script glyphs. For example, both `$^*$` and `$[ρ]$` result in intersecting glyphs. (As a side note, ConTeXt renders both correctly, while XeLaTeX renders the first correctly but not the second).

Khaled did propose a workaround, but since it involves rebuilding the format, I'm not interested. Also, I can't wait for the bugfix to happen (I have a thesis to deliver). So, is there a workaround that only involves some code in the preamble?

A solution for XeLaTeX would also be valuable for me, since it's very easy to switch to it (although I'd prefer to use LuaLaTeX).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using AMSLaTeX, then, following Vafa Khalighi's email at
http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2011-October/030337.html
you seem to need to do (1):

```
\everymath\expandafter{\the \everymath \luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay \luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
```

instead of simply (2)

```
\everymath{\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
\everydisplay{\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
```

I myself found on a big book with a lot of AMSLaTeX that LuaLaTeX gave errors with (2) but worked fine with (1).

Comment: Could you give an example of the errors that happened with (2)?

Comment: @MateusAraújo You'll remove anything that has already been set up by packages, _etc._, which alter math mode behaviour. The AMS Math system in particular needs to use these hooks, and without them all sorts will go wrong.

Comment: Just for future reference: to use this with `TikZ`'  `matrix of math nodes`, `ampersand replacement=\&` is needed.

Answer (score 14):

Incidentally I was thinking about less invasive solution last night and it occurred to me using LuaTeX's catcode tables might help. The code below will reset catcodes to the "standard" LaTeX catcode table (whatever that means) inside math mode, I don't know what side effects this might have (hopefully none).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\everymath{\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
\everydisplay{\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}

\begin{document}
$^*$ \quad $[ρ]$
\end{document}
```

A better solution would involve saving the current catcode table, switching to `\CatcodeTableLaTeX` using `\everymath` and then switching back to the saved catcode table after math (but there seem not to be an "every after math" hook, so I've no idea how to do that), to localise the effect of switching catcode tables. **Update:** thanks to egreg's comment below, it seems switching catcode table inside `\everymath` is already localised to math mode.

Comment: Works like a charm! The little testing I did hasn't revealed any side effects yet. Have you ever got around to understanding XeTeX's problem?

Comment: The catcode table change seems to be undone when math mode is left: if I put the catcode table change in `\everymath` and then ask for the catcode of `` after the formula, LuaTeX returns again 11.

Comment: Well this answer one of my questions on the luatex mailing list: As I suspected it is possible to reset the catcodes simply in the document. The second question remains: which letters are affected? On the luatex list is looked as if you meant the normal "P" (which I couldn't really believe) but here it looks more like special chars. Can you tell some of the affected unicode points? (At best simply the unicode numbers).

Comment: @egreg: thanks, I tried that and indeed the catcode outside math mode is not affected. I updated my answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't know what Unicode code points are affected so I though resetting undoing the catcode part of `luatex-unicode-letters.tex` inside math mode would be the safest/easiest. By `P` I really meant U+1D443 (which what unicode-math will convert it to by default).

Comment: @MateusAraújo: I'm not sure why XeTeX is not applying the italic correction in the second case.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, this affects every character which has italic correction. I can't really say which are they, because a font can simply not have this information. But I'd say it affects everything which is italic; I just gave  as an example because it was more dramatic. But the rendering of even a simple $f(x)$ is wrong.