# LuaTeX: Wrong/missing italic correction in TeXLive 2015 vs 2014

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math, kerning

Italic correction for OTF math fonts seems to be broken in LuaTeX in TL15.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  V^* \quad T^6 \quad T) \quad VT
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with TL14 gives
[image: Example with TL14]
and TL15:
[image: Example with TL15]

There is no problem for upright letters (`\mathup{T}`).

Using the .otf font from 2014 with TL15 produced the same result as with the 2015 font.

I can remember having similar problems with TL11/12.

So the question is: what caused this change and how can I fix it?

Comment: Terrible regression! This should indeed be fixed as soon as possible!

Comment: Does it only happen for Latin Modern? Or for all math fonts?

Comment: @MaxNoe Also for XITS Math and TeX Gyre Termes Math (the ones I tried). On the other hand, it doesn't happen for the standard math fonts, so some bad interactions with `unicode-math` and `luaotfload` seems to be happening.

Comment: The italic correction for U+1D449 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL V is correctly computed to 2.14pt, but the kern is not inserted.

Comment: On the other hand, an attempt with Plain LuaTeX and `luaotfload` works.

Comment: It seems that the workaround suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33828/4427 works.

Comment: @egreg: Could it be that the new unicode catcode settings in the latex format are responsable?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think you got it!

Comment: I can't believe that [reporting it](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=933) on the LuaTeX tracker doesn't get a solution, but posting it here gets a workaround in 3 hours...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem has a long history. It was brought up in 2011, as far as I know, with a [message to the TeX Live mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2011-October/030295.html); the thread went on also in the [LuaTeX list](http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2011-October/003264.html).

The problem is that LuaTeX doesn't add the italic correction in math mode after characters having category code 11. Indeed, in TeX Live 2011, the output from your code would be the same as you get now.

See [How can I enable italic correction for LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/how-can-i-enable-italic-correction-for-luatex) for finding a workaround that applies also to the present version of LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  V^* \quad T^6 \quad T) \quad VT
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem was circumvented by changing the default category codes for math letters to 12. However, as suggested by Ulrike Fischer, the new release of LaTeX (2015/01/01) has changed back the category codes to 11 for every character that qualifies as a letter and so the problem has reappeared.

[Quoting Joseph Wright in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22548788#22548788)

> That's a bit of a problem: we are for a start looking at fixing `\CatcodeTableLaTeX` so it has the right catcodes

so the workaround is not guaranteed to be valid in the future (but I hope some better remedy will be found in the meantime).

Comment: The next version of unicode-math will also take steps to work around this problem.

Comment: fixed with unicode-math 0.8

Comment: But not for non-letters like integral signs