# How do I get italic correction in LuaLaTex with unicode-math and \left \right?

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math, kerning, italic-correction

The story about italic correction in LuaLaTeX when using `unicode-math` seems to be an [old](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/how-can-i-enable-italic-correction-for-luatex/31440) [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253512/luatex-wrong-missing-italic-correction-in-texlive-2015-vs-2014). However, the issue does not appear to be fixed. Here is what it looks like with `unicode-math`

[image: without italic correction]

and without

[image: with italic correction]

Note the yellow box right to the second *f*, which indicates kerning. It looks even worse when using the [Libertinus font](https://github.com/alerque/libertinus), then the *f* and the > really overlap:

[image: missing italic correction with libertinus]

I guess this is because Libertinus defines the right border of the *f* to be different.

Here is the code used to generate the last screenshots:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

% enable italic correction
\everymath\expandafter{\the \everymath \luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\th[enter image description here][4]e \everydisplay \luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}

\newcommand{\luatexcatcodetable}{}
\newcommand{\CatcodeTableLaTeX}{}

\newcommand*{\norm}[1]{{\ensuremath{\left\|{#1}\right\|}}}
\newcommand*{\inner}[1]{{\ensuremath{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle}}}

\begin{document}
   \[
       \inner{f, f}       \hspace{2em}
       \norm{f}_2^2       \hspace{2em}
       \inner{g, g}       \hspace{2em}
       \norm{g}_2^2       \hspace{2em}
   \]
\end{document}
```

Also, dropping the `\left` and `\right` makes it looks as it should:

[image: corrected libertinus math]

Unfortunately the [once recommended workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33828/18357)

```
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLaTeX}
```

gives me the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> \@displaytrue \luatexcatcodetable 
                              \CatcodeTableLaTeX
```

It looks like both commands `\luatexcatcodetable` and `CatcodeTableLaTeX` do not exist anymore. Adding

```
\newcommand{\luatexcatcodetable}{}
\newcommand{\CatcodeTableLaTeX}{}
```

makes my code compile (note that I did not have to use `\renewcommand`!), but obviously this has then no effect on italic correction. Any idea how to get italic correction now?

Comment: Please show the code the generated the screenshots you posted. The reason I ask is that I am unable to reproduce the screenshot with what I consider to be standard LaTeX commands. E.g., `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math} \setmathfont{Libertinus Math} \begin{document} \[ \langle f,f\rangle \quad \lVert f\rVert_2^2 \quad \langle g,g\rangle \quad \lVert g\rVert_2^2  \] \end{document}`

Comment: @Mico I added the code.

Comment: What is that catcodetable business supposed to do?

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm no expert, but if you click the old questions above, it looks like (at least historically) the cat code of letters in math code was set to 11 (instead of 12, which happens with `pdflatex`), and this prevented italic correction. The commands should enable the standard catcodes. But I don't even know what the catcodes of letters in math mode are at the moment (how would I check this?)

Comment: I think you found a bug in luaotfload (or in the font). I've built a Plain TeX reproducer and pinged the maintainers in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60968585#60968585

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for your support!

Comment: @red_trumpet It seems to go even deeper than just luaotfload. I've also reported this problem to the LuaTeX developers: https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2022-April/007701.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498776/lualatex-too-little-space-inside-f-bigl/498799#498799) I got the solution to add `\mathitalicsmode=1` to the preamble. If I understand correctly, this enables italic correction in math mode. To obtain the desired result, one also has to remove the surrounding brackets `{ ... }`, otherwise italic correction is not applied (except if there is a single  character `{f}`, then it seems to work. Why?) So the following code example works fine:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\mathitalicsmode=1

\begin{document}
   \[
       \left\langle f,f \right\rangle
   \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Braces create a sub_mlist but probably there is an optimization where the sub_mlist is omitted if it's only a single character. Normally the use of `{...}` is in inline math to prevent linebreaks, as in `${a + b}$` because `+` is a valid breakpoint for TeX.

Comment: @HenriMenke Removing braces when the math sublist contains a single character has been a TeX feature from the beginning.

Comment: @red_trumpet The next version of LuaTeX will have `\mathitalicsmode=2` to deal with the sub_mlist problem: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/commit/a7578ef54e1528f398f50aa910816332460866c5

Comment: @HenriMenke I saw snippets with some `…old…` and `…new…` macro identifiers. As *old* and *new* depend on the time, the folks that read these identifiers in a few years (or, in the worst case, months) might not know what old and new would refer to. So the developer might consider giving more descriptive names.