# Are the widths of , , and  in TeX Gyre Termes Math really equal?

Tags: luatex, width, lengths, tex-gyre-math

It was a surprise to me when feeding `lualatex` with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}% or \setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\begin{document}
Width of $L$: \setbox0\hbox{$L$}\the\wd0. \text{Width of}\ $Y$:\ \setbox0\hbox{$Y$}\the\wd0. \text{Width of}\ $Z$:\ \setbox0\hbox{$Z$}\the\wd0.
\end{document}
```

yielded

[image: widths output]

Are the widths of the three symbols REALLY equal?  I find it hard to believe because these numbers look way too nice, occupying only 3 decimal digits each.  I might imagine that really different lengths (given in sp or some other unit) were rounded up to the same number while converting to pt.  Is it really so?  If so, is it possible to distinguish between the widths of math-mode , , and  from inside LuaLaTeX?  If so, how?  (After all, running `xelatex` on the same input provides us with three different numbers. Also, running `pdflatex` (with `\usepacakge{amsmath}` instead of `\usepackage{unicode-math}`+`\setmathfont{…}`) yields three different numbers.)

Comment: What is your question? Character widths are not physical lengths that can be measured, we are not using hot metal. They are simply a length valued property set by the font designer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it; question reformulated.

Comment: I don't see any real difference in the formulation. Why do you expect the font designer to have set values that differ by small fractions of a pt??????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A contrary question: why should we expect the font designer to have set the same value for three different symbols?  If we take a look at what pdflatex+amsmath yield for the standard math fonts (I believe, Computer Modern), we get three different values: “Width of L: 6.80557pt. Width of Y: 8.02779pt. Width of Z: 7.54167pt.” (For whatever reason, there was a space between “Y” and “:” in the text layer of the output PDF file; I removed this space in the above quotation.)

Comment: classically in tfm fonts you can only have 18 different widths _in the whole font_

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh. I didn't know that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I see that 18 is the maximum?  When I run `lualatex` over https://pastebin.com/raw/pWLUUHuP, I get https://pastebin.com/raw/hqEmNf2j . Feeding this into `sort` and then `uniq`, we get 26 different numbers: https://pastebin.com/raw/ju9eX3Nv . And 26>18. I don't know how to see this maximum of 18 using `pdflatex`.

Comment: actualy 16, Knuth writes in the metafont sources: The actual width of a character is \\{width}|[width_index]|, in design-size
units; this is a device for compressing information, since many characters
have the same width. Since it is quite common for many characters
to have the same height, depth, or italic correction, the \.{TFM} format
imposes a limit of 16 different heights, 16 different depths, and
64 different italic corrections.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, got it.

Comment: But I can not then explain your test file, I may comment later

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm. I thought the quotation you wrote would apply to tfm text fonts and original TeX, whereas the modern setup with lualatex might do something else (perhaps, load lmroman10-regular.otf for text and cmmi10.pfb for math).

Comment: otf sure but you can use that file with luatex or pdftex and it uses cmmi10.tfm (easier to use \showthe than \the as then:  `grep '^>' file.log  | sort | uniq | wc -l` actually despite the 16 in the doc the size of the width array is a variable nw, so but I'm sure I have seen metafont adjust widths to fit the table (but it was all  long time ago) see `texdoc tftopl` for a description of tfm format

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Doesn't the `|char_info|` array have 8 bits reserved for width? So 256 different widths. One each, since there are 256 slots in a tfm. But there seem to be 16 possible different heights and depths and 64 possible values for italic correction.

Comment: @mickep ah of course my memory lost the different handling of width v height, thanks

Comment: Widths are unlimited, height and depths are limited to 16 different numbers in TFM files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

character lengths are not measured properties that depend on some accuracy of measurement, they are properties set by the font designer.

Modifying your example to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}% or \setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\begin{document}
Width of $L$: \setbox0\hbox{$L$}\the\wd0. \text{Width of}\ $Y$:\ \setbox0\hbox{$Y$}\the\wd0. \text{Width of}\ $Z$:\ \setbox0\hbox{$Z$}\the\wd0.


L 
\the\fontcharwd\textfont0 119871,
\the\fontcharic\textfont0 119871,

Y 
\the\fontcharwd\textfont0 119884,
\the\fontcharic\textfont0 119884,

Z 
\the\fontcharwd\textfont0 119885,
\the\fontcharic\textfont0 119885,

\end{document}
```

You get

[image]

with luatex, and

[image]

With xetex.

So the three characters have the same width but different italic correction.

luatex, in contrast to xetex, does not add italic correction at the end of the math which explains why you get different box widths with xetex.

Comment: Curious, does pdflatex or classic latex add the italic correction?

Comment: yes but there is a long and painful history about italic correction in opentype math luatex has "comments" about that and parameters to control when it is used @dedded

Comment: Is no italic correction the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Gaussler that depends on your desires

Comment: @Gaussler `texdoc luatex` section 7.5.5

Comment: Ticked. Thx! All answers so far are excellent, and this one is ticked simply so as to maintain the balance between David and Enrico (and because micrep he/she doesn't want this; cf. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62212797#62212797).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But the LuaTeX behaviour is intentional?

Comment: @Gaussler yes, although latex doesn't really have a good interface to setting the extra parameters based on font choice. classic TeX math fonts do not use "italic correction" to correct italic. the advance width of the character is always "width+ic" and "width" is used for subscript position. Some OTF math fonts follow this, but some use "width" as the advance width and use the separate subscript cutin parameter to kern subscripts closer and use italic correction just as would be used in text fonts. Basically the system can not tell what the font params mean

Answer (score 9):

Yes and no. The three characters have the same advance width 556. If we only look at that, the orange boxes below, we see (here the characters are squeezed together to make it more clear that the orange boxes have the same width):

[image: LYZ on top of each other]

We notice that the L and Z stick out to the left while Y and Z stick out to the right (in fact L also sticks out to the right, but very very little, see below). If we look at the font data, we see the following:

```
  [119871]={ -- L
   ["boundingbox"]={ -8, 0, 559, 653 },
   ["index"]=454,
   ["math"]={
    ["accent"]=267,
    ["italic"]=31,
   },
   ["unicode"]=119871,
   ["width"]=556,
  [119884]={ -- Y
   ["boundingbox"]={ 78, 0, 633, 653 },
   ["index"]=467,
   ["math"]={
    ["accent"]=362,
    ["italic"]=105,
   },
   ["unicode"]=119884,
   ["width"]=556,
  },
  [119885]={ -- Z
   ["boundingbox"]={ -6, 0, 606, 653 },
   ["index"]=468,
   ["math"]={
    ["accent"]=362,
    ["italic"]=78,
   },
```

- The (advance) widths are indeed equal.
- The bounding boxes shown are `{xbottomleft, ybottomleft, xtopright, ytopright}`. The negative values in the first slot for L and Z indicate that they stick out to the left. The values in the third slot indicates that they do in fact all stick out to the right (the L very little).
- We notice that the characters have different amounts of italic correction.

Here I would consider the answer to be complete, but since the other answers wrote about luatex and xetex doing things differently, let me add something about the italic correction in math. In luatex you have the possibility to add italic correction as well (by setting `\mathitalicsmode` to 1 or 2, I think). I think that the reason it is not added by default is that if one reads the [vague specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/math#mathitalicscorrectioninfo-table) it seems that it should not always be added. The situation today is that there are some math fonts, like cambria, garamond-math and lucida (and probably some more) that somehow follow the spec and do not rely on italic corrections (but on kerns), and then there are the rest (like Termes) that relies on the old TeX way with italic correction.

In the last few weeks I have discussed these issues with Hans Hagen a lot, in the context (pun intended) of the newer luametatex engine. Our aim has been to have a spacing model that works both with the old TeX-like fonts and with the newer ones. If we use italic corrections, a formula can look like this (italic corrections marked in blue):

[image: a formula with italic corrections]

As can be seen, the italic correction is always added, and in case of a subscript, removed. Since italic correction in opentype math is not really italic correction, we thought that maybe we could get rid of it alltogether, and replace it by corner kerns. Then it can look like this:

[image: a formula with corner kerns]

The output is (hopefully) the same. Notice that the width of the orange box with the Z is changed, and that there are two corner kerns added (one bottom right for the subscript, and one top left for the prescript).

The reason that the orange box is enlarged to the left in order to have a method that also works for difficult characters, like lower case italic f that in some fonts sticks out a lot to the left and right from the orange box. Compare the following to examples, and you will understand why.

[image: S(f) with italic corrections]

[image: S(f) with kerns]

Comment: Thx!!! `\mathitalicsmode` can be 0 or 1 according to my `texdoc luatex`, not 1 or 2.

Comment: I'm quite perplexed about the choice of the bounding box for Y.

Comment: @egreg So should we change it in the .otf font? I'd be eager to do that with fontforge at least locally if it results in better typesetting and if I know what to do exactly.

Comment: @AlbertNash I think the [value 2 is new](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642030/how-do-i-get-italic-correction-in-lualatex-with-unicode-math-and-left-right/642079#comment1600539_642079).

Comment: @egreg Why? The tighter box fits well with traditional TeX. The subscript is placed tight to it.

Comment: @mickep I'm concerned with the white space at the left.

Comment: This Q/A is about math, but the same problem occurs with text.  @egreg is right.  If a paragraph is set in italic, and a line in the middle starts with W or Y, it is visibly indented, and looks pretty awful.  I'm not sure whether microtype corrects it.  Needs to be looked at, in my opinion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Given your input, I've just asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662029 ; please feel free to comment and/or improve the question if you wish…

Comment: Isn't the answer to the question about bounding box that Termes uses the same bounding box for text italic as for math italic? In contrast, for Latin modern, the text italic Y has a big left side bearing, but the math italic Y does not.

Answer (score 5):

You're not measuring the width of the characters, but of some math formulas. And math formulas are treated differently by LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, as the former doesn't add a trailing italic correction.

If you compile the following with XeLaTeX, you get that, indeed, the characters have the same width, namely 5.56pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

$x$

\the\fontcharwd\textfont0 `

\the\fontcharwd\textfont0 `

\the\fontcharwd\textfont0 `

Width of $L$: \sbox0{$L$}\the\wd0.

Width of $Y$: \sbox0{$Y$}\the\wd0.

Width of $Z$: \sbox0{$Z$}\the\wd0.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I guess, adding `$x$` is a workaround against a zero-producing kludge of XeLaTeX , isn't it?

Comment: @AlbertNash That's in order that math fonts are assigned before inquiring `\textfont2`.

Comment: @egreg sorry yes, comment deleted